# Magento - How do I insert multiple page content into my home page template?

Tags: magento

I have a home page template and I want to pull content from other pages and have them display in the home page template.

Comment: This is too vague for anyone to provide you a real answer. Can you please edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally answered my own question. You use static blocks instead of pages. These are located under the CMS menu in the back room. Then you use this code to display the static block in the html:`<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('staticblockname')->toHtml() ?>`

Comment: Just wanted to add how to do similar via CMS Page/Blocks: `{{block type="catalog/product_new" product_id="1" template="catalog/product/view/your_new_page.phtml"}}`